# How can I improve my select query to make it faster?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of employees (roughly 4.5 million) which have columns called `job_title` and `domain`.

I wish to be able to create and run dynamic queries to select specific employees based on the job title and whose domain is also within the array of domains provided.

How it works, is a user on the front-end ends up with a big array of domains (anywhere from 200 - 10,000+), they then enter two things:

1. Which job titles they want **included**
2. Which job titles they want **excluded**

So we then build a query that ends up looking like this:

```
SELECT employee_id
FROM employee
WHERE (
        domain LIKE '%shetlandfoods.co.uk' 
        OR domain LIKE '%example1.co.uk' 
        OR domain LIKE '%example2.co.uk'

        -- About 50 additional domains in this list

        OR domain LIKE '%example50.co.uk'
    ) 
    AND (job_title LIKE '%Manager%' OR job_title LIKE '%Director%') 
    AND (job_title NOT LIKE '%Assistant%')
```

(**Note that the list of domains is extremely long, and may include thousands of domains(!)**)

Now, a query like this takes around 230 seconds, and that's only with around 180 domains! Imagine using thousands; it'd take forever.

I was wondering if there's any way I can optimize/change this query to make it run a bit faster? Or is there anything I can do to the database?

Comment: `most of it is just domains, so just skip to the end` All those unindexed  LIKE filters are probably the problem.

Comment: What is the source of the `domain` data and can you show us a few samples?  My thought is that maybe you can preprocess this data somehow to make the query easier.

Comment: Pro-tip: SQL can contain line feeds ;-)

Comment: If you reversed the domain elements, then indexing would work better - it's much quicker to look for 'uk.co.shetland.stronach%' than '%stronach.shetland.co.uk'

Comment: It smells a little like you've got a bad schema design, to me.  For example, if the domain endings are related to, say, `employers` or `customers` then you could normalise those out to another table with an int PK as an ID column and just reference the parent ID in the employee table.  Numerical values are much quicker to search, especially when indexed.

Comment: Also I would be to break the domains into domainname subdomain and tld and put this in different fields. Than you can query like with = instead of like which is quite faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two options which come to mind (the second suggested by @paul above in his comment).

One is that you could pre process the data in the `domain` column such that it only has the exact domain and nothing else.  This is a well-known problem and is relatively easy to handle in Java or JavaScript.  If this were done, then you can put an index on the `domain` column and use a `WHERE` clause looking something like the following:

```
WHERE domain IN ('shetlandfoods.co.uk',
                 'alac.shetland.co.uk',
                 'malakofflimited.co.uk',
                 ...)
```

Another option might be to compare the reverse of the domain against the reverse of the terms you had in your original `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
WHERE REVERSE(domain) LIKE 'ku.oc.sdoofdnaltehs%' OR
      REVERSE(domain) LIKE 'ku.oc.dnaltehs.cala%' OR
      REVERSE(domain) LIKE 'ku.oc.detimilffokalam%' OR
      ...
```

You could even store the reverse of the `domain` from your app/UI layer so that you don't have to force MySQL to compute the reverse for each term in the `WHERE` clause.

I might lean towards the first option, assuming you have the bandwidth to extract out the domains before hitting MySQL.

Comment: **REVERSE(domain)** is not the best way to do that. It much more better to store the **REVERSE(domain)** Value in a new field. Than you can use a index. in your case its always a full table scan

Comment: I have an index on both `domain` and `job_title` with the same names.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I suggested computing and storing the reverse outside of MySQL.  I prefer extracting the true domain, in the app layer, as you go along and then just comparing with equals.  And in this case an index should speed things up.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne - but **LIKE '%....'** dosent use a index. it is always a full table scan

Comment: Okay, so if I use **domain IN**, will that use indexing?

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Yes, but then you need to be able to do either exact matching, or the wildcard should ideally appear at the end.

Comment: What about the job title afterwards? Will it not use indexing because of the `%job_title%`?

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne No, the leading wildcard would prevent the index from being used.  But you only have a few of these terms and this likely isn't what is slowing down your query.  Make the domain comparisons run fast, and you might find the query speed to already be acceptable.

Comment: I did it. Got my query down from 230 seconds to less than 2 seconds. I guess indexing is a really big thing, never knew much about it before now. Thanks!

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne When MySQL uses an index, you can think of it as almost instantly knowing where something is in a table.  Without an index, it generally needs to do something called a full table scan which means it might have to check _every_ record in the table.  This can be very slow as you have just seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can create temp table as follows for this kind of scenario:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE domain_values (
  domain_value VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Then insert all domains as:

```
INSERT INTO domain_values  VALUES ('%shetlandfoods.co.uk'), ('%shopshetlandtoday.co.uk'), ........;
```

Then select as:

```
SELECT e.employee_id FROM employee e JOIN domain_values d ON (e.domain LIKE d.domain_value)  AND
     (e.job_title LIKE '%Manager%' OR e.job_title LIKE '%Director%') AND (e.job_title NOT LIKE '%Assistant%');
```

Comment: What's the benefit of doing so?

Comment: This will be more efficient than above one.

Answer (score 0):

reversing the text like

`WHERE REVERSE(domain) LIKE 'ku.oc.sdoofdnaltehs%' OR
      REVERSE(domain) LIKE 'ku.oc.dnaltehs.cala%' OR
      REVERSE(domain) LIKE 'ku.oc.detimilffokalam%'...`

is one option you can try another you can also try this

`SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE INSTR( domain,'shetlandfoods.co.uk' ) > 0`

this is faster then `LIKE %text%`